# Correct syntax to assign a method based on datatype to an inherited abstract method

Tags: c#

Newbie question. Say I have an abstract class A  with an abstract method Edit(). Edit will need to be overridden depending on the data type. It is generic in class A.

```
public abstract class A
{
   .....
   public abstract void Edit();
   ....
}
```

Now class B implements class A, but has different constructors based on the data type. So constructor #1 does Edit_1(), and constructor #2 does Edit_2().

So I would like to write class B something along the lines of:

```
  public class B : A
{
   public B(dataType1): base()
   {
       this.Edit = Edit_1;
    }

   public B(dataType2): base()
   {
       this.Edit = Edit_2;
   }

   void Edit_1() {....}
   void Edit_2() {....}

}
```

Can this be done? What is the correct syntax to do this? Is there a better way?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to solve a problem with inheritance where you really should use composition - Add a parameter to your constructor that injects an instance of a type that implements `IEditable` which has an `Edit` method that accepts an instance of type `A`.

```
public abstract class A
{


}

public interface IEditable
{
    public void Edit(A myInstance);

}
public class B : A
{
    private IEditable _editor;
    public B(IEditable editor)
    {
        _editor = editor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're describing sounds like it may be better suited for an interface or a generic class.  Having a single class implement different behavior depending on a data type typically indicates a misuse of polymorphism.

Nevertheless, this can be accomplished using a delegate:

```
public class B : A
{
    private Action editFunction;

    public B(string foo)
        : base()
    {
        editFunction = Edit_1;
    }

    public B(int bar)
        : base()
    {
        editFunction = Edit_2;
    }

    public override void Edit()
    {
        editFunction();
    }

    void Edit_1() { }
    void Edit_2() { }
}
```

Comment: This is very close to want I wanted, but why is it a "misuse of polymorphism" ? How better could this be done? Thanks.

Comment: I can't make a firm recommendation without knowing your exact situation, but if there are two different behaviors depending on data type, it might make more sense to have a different implementing class for each data type.  Rather than setting up different `Edit` paths within the same class, you use a factory (or other method) to create the right `A` subclass up front, and then let each subclass handle its own implementation of `Edit`.

Comment: Actually, I intended the same behavior regardless of the datatype. Your answer is what I was asking for, but better yet your comment on not doing this was most important. Heading your advice and BrokenGlass has led to a much improved application. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the problem that you are planting us.

But you can do the following, I am asuming that  `this.Edit` is an event and you are trying to set a delegate depending of the datatype that came in the constructor.

so write just one contructor and say:

```
public B(Object Obj)
        : base()
    {
        swich (Obj.GetType())
        {
            Case DataType1:
            this.Edit = Edit_1;
            break;
            Case DataType2:
            this.Edit = Edit_2;
            default:
            throw new Exception("Object Type [" + Obj.GetType().FullName + "] not supported");
        }
    }
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, try explain it better and i will find a better solution.

**UPDATE:** To Answerd the Comment

So, you should use the post marked as answer, but [A] must be IEditable, and must contain a method called Edit. then your B class must implement [A] and you will write different code portions in each [B] Edit method. then when you intance [B] like this:

A is IEditable that contain the Edit method.

```
public class B : A {....}

IEditable Interface = new B;
```

[B] can be any class that implement [A] that is IEditable.

Call `Interface.Edit` and will execute the code of this [B] Datatype

Comment: this.Edit is a method--not an event. I am essentially trying to let the compiler decide which constructor to use based on the datatype of the argument. However, I was hoping to use a construct something similar to event/delegate. Any ideas?